# AJAX not loading my index.php

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a **sign_ in form** and when I try to login, the method **window.location = "index.php"** does not load my index.php page. But after I click login and load the sign_in form in a new tab the index.php page loads.

```
success: function(response){ 
    if(response == "0"){                 
        alert ("Wrong User Id or Password");
    }else{                                  
        window.loaction = "index.php"                                   
    }
}
```

What needs to be done so that the index.php page loads?

Comment: typo error, its `location` and not `loaction`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is you spelled it wrong, its `location` and not `loaction`

Comment: Exactly what I was going to say.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.location.href = "index.php"
```

Comment: Both should work fine, you don't have to add HREF. It's not a must-do.

Comment: Please firstly change `window.loaction` to `window.location` and if still doesn't work try with `window.location.href`